# QTP/UFT full documentation

Tags: qtp

I am looking for QTP/UFT documentation similar to this one (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) on Java.
I have lots of questions about objects,functions and their parameters or possible values.
For example I searched:

image capturing options but I only found some example `qtApp.Options.Run.ImageCaptureForTestResults = "OnError".`

I know there are more options not only "OnError" but I don’t know what the correct strings are.

Or

```
Set qtApp = CreateObject("QuickTest.Application")
qtApp.Open "d:\Test1 ",True
```

What does the second parameter do?

Anyway, I have lots of questions about objects,functions and their parameters or possible values, so if you can give me a link to any documentation where I can find all functions/object with their parameter list and other inputs I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QTP/UFT has excellent documentation/help file.

I assume you have UFT installed. Go to help.

[image]

Select the UFT Automation Object Model reference. Navigate to the object you are looking for.

[image]

The second parameter in the below statement is optional. If it is TRUE, it opens the test in ReadOnly mode. FALSE is edit mode. FALSE is default.

```
qtApp.Open "d:\Test1 ",True
```

Answer (score 1):

For taking screenshots you can use CaptureBitmap.

syntax :

```
Objecthierarchy.Capturebitmap "filename.bmp",true
```

example :

```
Browser("").capturebitmap "C:\name.bmp", true
Desktop.capturebitmap "",true
```